# What is the best way in xonsh to loop over the lines of a file?

Tags: python, bash, xonsh

What is the best way in the [`xonsh`](https://github.com/xonsh/xonsh/) shell to loop over the lines of a text file?

**(A)** At the moment I'm using

```
for l in !(cat file.txt): 
    line = l.strip()
    # Do something with line...
```

**(B)** Of course, there is also

```
with open(p'file.txt') as f:
    for l in f:
        line = l.strip()
        # Do something with line...
```

I use (A) because it is shorter, but **is there anything even more concise?** *And* preferably folding the `l.strip()` into the loop?

*Note:* My main interest is conciseness (in the sense of a small character count) - maybe using xonsh's special syntax features if that helps the cause.

Answer (score 2):

You can fold `str.strip()` into the loop with [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#map):

(A):

```
for l in map(str.strip, !(cat file.txt)):
    # Do something with line...
```

(B):

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    for l in map(str.strip, f):
        # Do something with l..
```

Comment: Yes, both versions work. I have just tested them in xonsh 0.8.3.

Answer (score 1):

Minimal character count could even involve relying on your python implementation to release the file at the end of execution, rather than doing it explicitly:

```
for l in map(str.strip, open('file.txt')):
    # do stuff with l
```

Or using the p'' string to make a path in xonsh (this does properly close the file):

```
for l in p'file.txt'.read_text().splitlines():
    # do stuff with l
```

`splitlines()` already removes the new line characters, but not other whitespace.

Comment: True...I misinterpreted your need for conciseness as a need for readability.

Comment: Edited my response for brevity in code. Note that CPython will auto-close your file at program exit but other Python implementations may not.

Comment: Wow, the version with the p'' notation looks now pretty compelling to me. Thx.

Comment: Just realised that the method on `Path` objects is called `read_text`, not `get_text`. Edited the answer accordingly.